# Using unittest to check "--help" flag output

Tags: python, unit-testing, argparse, stringio

I have some code that parses command line options using argparse.

For example:

```
# mycode.py

import argparse

def parse_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser('my code')
    # list of arguments
    # ...
    # ...
    return vars(parser.parse_args())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parse_args()
```

I would like to use unittest to check the output of the help function. I also don't want to change the actual code unless there is no other solution.
The help action has a `SystemExit` call built into it after printing to stdout, so I have had to try and catch it in the unittest.

Here is my unittest code with the following steps:

1) Set the `sys.argv` list to include the `-h` flag.

2) Wrap the function call in a context manager to prevent the `SystemExit` being viewed as an error.

3) Switch the `sys.stdout` temporarily to an `io.StringIO` object so I can inspect it without having it print to screen.

4) Call the function in a `try...finally` block so the `SystemExit` isn't fatal.

5) Switch `sys.stdout` back to the real `stdout`.

6) Open a file to which I had previously saved the help text (by entering `python mycode.py -h > help_out.txt` in the terminal) to verify it is the same as the captured output from the `StringIO`.

```
import unittest
import mycode
import sys
import io

class TestParams(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        pass

    def test_help(self):
        args = ["-h"]
        sys.argv[1:] = args
        with self.assertRaises(SystemExit):
            captured_output = io.StringIO()
            sys.stdout = captured_output
            try:
                mycode.parse_args()
            finally:
                sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
                with open("help_out.txt", "r") as f:
                    help_text = f.read()
                    self.assertEqual(captured_output, help_text)

    def tearDown(self):
        pass
```

This code works, but the `captured_output` `StringIO` object is empty, so the test fails.

I am looking for an explanation as to what is going wrong with the captured output and/or an alternative solution.

Comment: Unittesting `argparse` is tricky.  `test_argparse.py` uses a subclass of `ArgumentParser` that redefines the `error ` and `exit` methods, and redirects `stdout` and `stderr`.  You could also test `help` output with `parser.format_help()` instead of the full `['-h']` mechanism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was very close. The `captured_output` wasn't actually empty - I just wasn't accessing the contents correctly.

Substitute `captured_output.get_value()` for `captured_value` in my example code and it works perfectly.